# Is it possible, and what is the best strategy, to pass objects by reference from one Activity to the next?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, reference

I have a simple Android application that uses an instance of a class, let's call it `DataManager`, to manage access to the domain classes in a Façade-like way. I initially designed it as a singleton which could be retrieved using static methods but I eventually got irritated with the messiness of my implementation and refactored to what I reckoned was a simpler  and cleaner idea.

Now the idea is that for each file that is opened, one `DataManager` is created, which they handles both file I/O and modification of the domain classes (e.g. `Book`). When starting a new Activity, I pass this one instance as a `Serializable` extra (I haven't got on to using `Parcelable` yet, but expect I will when I have the basic concept working), and then I grab the `DataManager` from the `Intent` in the `onCreate()` method of the new Activity.

Yet comparison of the objects indicates that the object sent from one activity is not identical (different references) to the object retrieved from the `Bundle` in the second Activity. Reading up on `Bundle` (on StackOverflow, etc.) suggests that Bundles cannot do anything other than pass-by-value.

So what is likely to be the cleanest and safest strategy for passing an object between Activities? As I see it I could

1. Forget about passing by reference and live with each `Activity` having its own DataManager object. Pass back the new `DataManager` every time I close an activity so that the underlying activity can use it. (The simple solution, I think.)
2. Go back to using a singleton `DataManager` and use a static method to get it from each `Activity`. (Not keen on using singletons again.)
3. Extend Application to create a sort of global reference to `DataManager`. (Again, not keen on the idea of globals.)

Is that a fair summary? Is there some other healthy strategy I could use?

Comment: Just a word about terminology: Java *always* uses pass-by-value - whether you're passing references or primitive types. Objects are never passed at all. I think I know what you mean, but using pass-by-reference is a bit of a distraction.

Comment: I'd prefer using the Singleton method, it's classically used for single instance classes with a global access point.

Comment: If you must use a Singleton, you can use an Application subclass. In my experience, it's better to avoid DAO classes in Android, and use ContentProviders. They are inherently available everywhere.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Sorry for the confusion, I think what I am trying to describe may be simpler than my description. I just want to ensure this one object is used for as long as this file is opened, and that only one object is opened for the file.

What I don't want to do, really, is use one `DataManager` for all files. My idea is that DataManagers are garbage collected after their associated file is closed, so a `DataManager` only ever is concerned with one file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach would be to create a service. The first activity would start the service and bind to it, when you launch a new intent, unbind the first activity and when second activity  starts, bind to the service.

This way you don't have to ever stop the service or worry about passing data between activities.

Comment: this is the best Android way to do the stuff.. It respects the android memory management strategies/concept

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have pass by reference so that option is out, I would suggest dependency injection for passing data between the activities. Otherwise definetely the singleton would be the way to go.

Comment: What sort of dependency injection are you suggesting? To be honest I hadn't realised that was an option on Android. Is it a simple option?

Answer (score 0):

The prescribed one is Going by implementing **Parcellable** interface, thats the way to pass Objects between Activities.. and the 2nd and better choice is to make a Singleton to be sure its single Object.

Comment: Would using Parcelable instead of Serializable mean just the one object is getting passed around, removing the need to pass it back to the previous activity after using it?

Answer (score 0):

Create your DataManager as a Singleton that implements [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Bind the service to your application in the manifest xml (see the link), and you will have a persistent singleton your activities can access without issues.

Passing parcellable arguments can quickly get very messy if you need to get a lot of data. The singleton approach, although usually considered an anti-pattern, works like a charm in cases like these. Just remember to not create multiple singletons that interact with one another.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an Application Subclass. It allows you to hold a single reference to the DataManger class and is persistent as long as your app lives.

A singleton with a static field will also work, but there are some place in the documentation where it says that the content of static fields is not a safe place to store your data. As I understand static fields should persist as long as your ClassLoader stays in memory. Therefore a singleton should only vanish if the whole process leaves the memory and in that case the application class will also leave the memory, but it will call the onDestroy methods of the Application and that enables you to safely close your DataManager and persist important data to memory.

That said to your two variations.

The Android way to go would be to make your DataManager a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). This will make it possible to access your Data from every Activity without holding a global reference.   I'm not sure how you would build a caching Content Provider that stays in memory and is not reinstantiated too often.